# When getting a JSON from the web and trying to process it I get "undefined" errors, while the log displays the data correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, http, undefined

I'm trying to process the json data I get from a server but when I try to do a .forEach, on it it says that the data I'm trying to work with is undefined while the console.log displays the correct values.

What could be the problem, am I missing an async/await from somewhere? Am I calling the data processing function too early? If yes how could it be solved?

Relevant parts of the component.ts:

```
all: any;
  constructor(private feedService: FeedService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchPosts();
    console.log(this.all);
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.feedService.getTags(this.all.posts[0]);
  }

  async fetchPosts() {
    (await this.feedService.getJSON(this.url)).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.all = data;
      console.log(this.all);
    });

  }
```

Relevant parts of the service:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public async getJSON(url: string) {
    return this.http.get<any>(url);
  }

  public async getTags(postData: any) {
    let tags = [];
    await postData['tags'].array.forEach(tag => { //This throws the error
      tags.push(tag); //Uncomplete processign code, for now it 
    });
    return tags;
  }
```

And here is a screenshot of the console output: [image]

Answer (score 0):

add `this.all?.posts[0]`
I think problem is that this.all is any type.
When this.all is null or undefined then this.all.posts cannot be read as it will try to read *undefined*.posts which is not possible

Answer (score 0):

When you try to access the "this.all.posts[0]" in "ngAfterContentInit" function "this.all" variable is still not set, is undefined. There are different solutions to this problem. One of them is you can just call the "this.feedService.getTags(this.all.posts[0])" function after you set the "      this.all = data;"

Answer (score 0):

`this.feedService.getTags` is being called with `this.all.posts[0]` before `this.all` is defined.

The response from the `fetchPosts` call is assigned to `this.all` at some point after the call is made. Since it's an asynchronous response from a server, you can't trust that it will have returned at any point, even when the `afterContentInit` hook fires.

What you need to do is wait until the subscription in `fetchPosts` hits and returns with data.

```
  all: any;
  constructor(private feedService: FeedService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchPosts();
  }

  async fetchPosts() {
    this.feedService.getJSON(this.url).subscribe((data) => {
      this.all = data;
      // It would be wise to add handling for posts being undefined here.
      this.feedService.getTags(this.all.posts[0]);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't seem to work, if I remove the await from the subscribe I get an error, I'm not sure hy because the official angular server communication tutorial did everything the same way... The error is "Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<Observable<any>>'", so something is off, I'm jsut not sure what, the only difference between my code and the code here: https://angular.io/guide/http is that my type is any because the json is way too complicated to make a model out of.

Comment: the `Property 'subscribe' does not exist...` error - specifically which function is that referring to?

Comment: It appaears if I try to subscribe to the getJSON function in fetchPosts if I don't await it

Comment: Try removing `async` from the definition for getJSON - it appears that's what's causing the issue. Returning an observable is still technically a synchronous operation. https://ibb.co/RNhHhZT

Comment: Okay now it as is in the angular example, but it still doesn't want to work, this is so weird. If I log the all in fetchposts after I I subscribe it logs it, but if I... wait a minute maybe the all just points to the "data" which loses it's value after. Let me test

Comment: Sadly no, I made a completely new copy of data and I gave that to "all" and it's still undefined when I try to log it after fetch posts, the weird thing is I wrote an if statement so that getTags() only runs if all is defined jet it still throws the error even that it shouldn't run, hmmm.

Comment: Can you post your updated code?

Comment: Yeah here it is, the getTags and getJSON didn't change much except they are no longer async :
`ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchPosts();
    console.log(this.all); //logs undefined
  }

  fetchPosts() {
    this.feedService.getJSON(this.url).subscribe((data) => {
      this.all = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
      console.log(this.all); //logs value
      if (this.all !== undefined) {
        this.feedService.getTags(this.all.posts[0]);
      }
    });

  }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249680/discussion-between-tanner-and-hex).